# Package Regular Files with JAR using build.gradle.kts in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle

**Question:** How do I include regular .txt config files within my JAR using `build.gradle.kts`?

**Problem:**

I need to create a JAR that can run independently of its file location. I use txt config files to set up my Spring Boot application. These files are under `main/resources/dummy/*`.

When I build the application, nothing under `dummy/*` gets added to the JAR.

Here is a visualisation of the file structure:

```
.
└── src
    └── main
        ├── kotlin
        │   └──<Source code> 
        └── resources
            ├── application.properties
            ├── dummy
            |   ├── cache
            |   │   ├── dataExample1.cache
            |   │   └── dataExample2.cache
            |   └── data
            |       ├── dataExample3.txt
            |       └── dataExample4.txt
            └── static
                └── <Static files>
```

Comment: FatJar has all the resources, including your files, required for jar to run. However, plain jar which is generated by jar task does not include your files. Not sure why you want to use plain jar, but my advice is to extend jar task so that you can include your files, too.

Comment: Hey @Umit. I believe I am using a fat jar. I have compiled the application via `gradle bootJar`, but the files under `main/resources/dummy are not being created :(

Answer (score 0):

I think by default, the bootJar task only copies files directly under resources, and folders named either "public" or "static". A good way to test this is to put your `dummy` folder under the `static` folder and see if it automagically gets included. If you want folders that aren't named those to be added to the jar, you need to add a copy task to the bootJar task in the gradle build. This is an example (in gradle 7.3) where I copy asciidoctor output into the static/docs directory of the jar

```
    bootJar {
        dependsOn(asciidoctor)
        if (project.hasProperty("doc")) {
            from ("${asciidoctor.get().outputDir}") {
                into("static/docs")
            }
        }
    }
```

Your's might look something like (syntax may be wrong, but hopefully you get the idea) which should include everything

```
    bootJar {
      from("src/main/resources") {
          include("**/*.*")
      }
    }
```

or (I think it'll create the dummy folder for you -- again, not tested)

```
    bootJar {
      from("src/main/resources/dummy") {
          into("dummy/")
      }
    }
```